# add operation on a pointer value C

Tags: c, pointers, addition

I'm having problems trying to create an assembly emulator program in C. There are 5 registers: REGA, REGB, REGC, REGX AND INSP, and 10 instructions: NOP, SET, AND (bitwise &), OR (bitwise |), ADD, SUB, SHL(<< left), SHR(>>), JMP.

The program reads instructions from a file; with lines containing the instruction and 2 arguments. In most cases the 1st argument is a register name (e.g. REGA) and the 2nd argument can be a register name or an integer.

I'm using sscanf to get the instructions from the file.

I'm having trouble with the ADD, SUB, SHL and SHR functions. My ADD function is:

```
int opcode_add(char* opcode, char *arg1, char *arg2){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_REGISTER; i++){ 
        if (strcmp(register_str[i],arg1) == 0){ 
            for(j = 0; j <=MAX_REGISTER; j++){ 
                if(strcmp(register_str[j],arg2) == 0){ 
                    *register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[i] + *register_ptr[j]; 
                    break;
                }else {
                    *register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[i] + atoi(arg2); 
                }       
            }

        }
    }
    INSP++; 
    return (0); 
}
```

The function works if 2 register arguments are passed. For example:

```
SET REGA 1
SET REGB 2
ADD REGA REGB
```

but not if a register and an integer are passed. For example:

```
SET REGA 2
ADD REGA 1
```

The problem is at this line:

```
*register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[i] + atoi(arg2);
```

I tried doing this:

```
int y = *register_ptr[i];
int k = atoi(arg2);
int result = y+k;
*register_ptr[i] = result;
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: This looks suspicious:  `for(j = 0; j <=MAX_REGISTER; j++)` The outer `for`'s terminating condition is `i < MAX_REGISTER` and both loops index `register_str`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say *what* didn't work - however, there is at least one error in the way you have structured the inner loop and the `if`. Whenever the inner loop sees a register that does not match the second operand, the `else` block will be executed - so *all* registers before the one specified by the second operand will be added to (and if the second operand is an int, *all* registers will be added to). The contents of the `else` block must be moved *after* the loop, and they must only be executed if the inner loop didn't find the register.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't receive any error messages. The problem is that the calculation isn't correct. For example, if I: SET REGA 1; then ADD REGA 1 - the else statement should be executed (because arg2 isn't a register, it's an int). This it does; however, the result from the calculation is wrong. In the example, the result I receive is incorrect.

Comment: @Maj: Yes, because the `else` will be executed _multiple_ times because of the error I described. Make sure you understand why that happens (either by debugging or by inserting `cout` statements that show when the `if` part and when the `else` part are being executed) before you try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't used the debugger; I've not tried it yet. I managed to fix it by moving the contents of the else statement after the first if.

Comment: @Maj: So the same `else` block is now after `if (strcmp(register_str[i],arg1) == 0)`? Then I think you have introduced another error: For instance, `ADD REGC 1` will now add 1 to all registers before `C`, and `ADD REGC REGA` will crash or produce a wrong result.

Comment: Yep, I put it there. But, I didn't put as an else block; just the code that was in it - within the if, before the 2nd loop. It seems to work. I just did SET REGC 1, ADD REGC 2; the result was indeed 3.

Comment: @Maj: Yes, `REGC` will get the correct value - but I believe that the values of `REGA` and `REGB` will have been changed as well. Try `SET REGA 0, SET REGB 0, SET REGC 1, ADD REGC 2`; `REGA` and `REGB` will probably become 2.

Comment: @Maj: Shahbaz' answer contains the solution to your problem, but I suggest that before looking at it, you try to solve it yourself - and don't solve it by moving the code from the `else` block somewhere else to see if it seems to work; instead, try to understand _why_ the current code does not work and figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are here:

```
for(j = 0; j <=MAX_REGISTER; j++){ 
    if(strcmp(register_str[j],arg2) == 0){ 
        *register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[i] + *register_ptr[j]; 
        break;
    }else {
        *register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[i] + atoi(arg2); 
    }       
}
```

First of all, you should check for `j < MAX_REGISTER` because your array (apparently) doesn't include `MAX_REGISTER` itself. But what is even more important, is that **you shouldn't try `atoi` as soon as one register name mismatches**.

What you have done now is that, if the second argument is not `REGA`, you immediately go to `else` and try `atoi`. What you *should* do is to check for all registers, if `arg2` was none of them, then try `atoi`:

```
bool found = false;
for(j = 0; j < MAX_REGISTER; j++){ 
    if(strcmp(register_str[j],arg2) == 0){ 
        *register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[i] + *register_ptr[j]; 
        found = true
        break;
    }       
}
if (!found)
    *register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[i] + atoi(arg2);
```